# How to use multiple types for the same property in Mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose

My use case is as follows: my events collection may store events from 2 types of users - admin users and regular users.
As admin users have a collection is the cluster, I'm referencing them from the events schema with a regular ref as follows:

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: false,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

My regular users however are not signed to the system (tracked by a cookie) and I would like to just save a string ID like this:

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }
});
```

How can I achieve this with Mongoose? I've ran across refPath but it seems to only reference different models (no string option).

Thanks in advance!